# Cannot open most apps, "Sign In To iTunes Store" required

Tags: ios

This issue keeps on coming back even after I sign in. How can I fix this?

Problem is my Apple ID password is stored on 1Password... and I cannot open it on my iPhone.

Not sure, but the issue might occur after I sync and backup my data to iTunes.

[image]

Comment: What iOS? I had a similar issue on 13.0 which went away after the first point update. I never did figure out what was upsetting it.

Comment: The issue is happening on iOS 12.4.1.

Comment: Then the obvious first step would be to update & see what happens.